# R Convert column to spatial objects - Polygon

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I have some polygon data as an csv file with this format:

```
"ID","name","geometry"
"1","A","list(c(-0.25291548373789, -0.251828087559847, -0.251065989114876, -0.24944850900495, 51.4652163826438, 51.4652280432439, 51.4652040920587, 51.4650720752044))"
"2","B","list(c(-0.26291548373789, -0.211828087559847, -0.231065989114876, -0.26944850900495, 51.1652163826438, 51.2652280432439, 51.3652040920587, 51.5650720752044))"
```

And, when I import it to Rstudio looks like this:
[image]

Which is what I'm looking for, but the type of data is not what I need:

```
 $ ID      : num [1:2] 1 2
 $ name    : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
 $ geometry: chr [1:2] ""list(c(-0.25291548373789, -0.2518280875598..."
```

What I need is this geometry column to an Spatial Object as Polygon, to be able to use it on Leaflet as:

```
addPolygons(data=test$geometry)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
test <- st_as_sf(test, wkt = 'geometry')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).